# BInd Jira test case and automation tests

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, jira, testcase, autotest

Now on my project we use TFS as TestCase management tool, issue tracking system and code management. But we want to move to JIRA and Bitbucket. In VisualStudio we have ability to bind TC to automation test and then run test suite with automation test. The question is: Is it possible to bind JIRA test case with automation test(UI tests, API tests used MSTest framework)? Is it possible to run automation test and see if test case pass\failed? Some reports?
Maybe there is possibility to develop some extension for this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, right now there are no built-in JIRA importer for data from Microsoft Team Foundation Server for Visual Studio.

However, there are complete third party solutions available which might help you between JIRA and TFS such as below:

- [TFS4JIRA](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.spartez.jira.plugins.bork.tfs4jira/cloud/overview)
- [MS TFS Connector for JIRA](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.go2group.ca.jira.tfs/cloud/overview)
- [UseTFS](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.pigsty.jira.plugin.usetfs/server/overview?_ga=1.227742237.1255447474.1455158083)